Envs Directories on Anaconda
I installed anaconda on D-drive, but it does have its folders in C drive in these locations - inside C:\Users\grelnob\.conda and C:\Users\grelnob\AppData\Local\conda
Here is the location of the envs directories
D:\AnacondaFinal\anacondaInstall\envs
C:\Users\grelnob\.conda\envs
C:\Users\grelnob\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs

And the anaconda prompt by default opens in the C-drive directory C:\Users\grelnob\ and by default, it is the base environment and it belongs *  D:\AnacondaFinal\anacondaInstall when I typed in conda env list. I want to create a new virtual environment for my project. I want to know if I should go to each of the directories where the envs directories exist, and then create virtual environment inside each of them or it will get automatically reflected if I do it from D-drive since that is where I installed anaconda.
I understand this could be considered a trivial question, because I have seen answers related to envs in anaconda. But I am unable to comment on the post to ask the author this question, plus I am not able to reach out to them other ways, which is why I have created this post.
Also, I recently removed all traces of anaconda and python due to conflicts in certain software packages and then installed only anaconda again. I do not want to get into this again, so I am trying to follow the best practices in anaconda while setting it up.
